# WinAPI - GetAdaptersAddresses() and GetAdaptersInfo() return different sets of IP addresses

Tags: windows, winapi, networking

I am facing an issue, where the two functions for enumerating the network adapters, `GetAdaptersInfo()` (IPv4 only) and `GetAdaptersAddresses()` (IPv4 + IPv6) return different results.

This is a sample of the results that I get from function `GetAdaptersInfo()`. There is one json object for each adapter:

```json
[
  {
    "ipAddresses": [
      {
        "ip": "10.x.x.x"
      }
    ],
    "interfaceIndex": 22
  },
  {
    "ipAddresses": [
      {
        "ip": "0.0.0.0"
      }
    ],
    "interfaceIndex": 29
  },
  {
    "ipAddresses": [
      {
        "ip": "169.254.89.20"
      }
    ],
    "interfaceIndex": 6
  },
  ...
]
```

In total, there are 8 adapters that I get from this function and 3 of them have an assigned IPv4 address. The rest of the adapters do not seem to have an IPv4 address and they have the "0.0.0.0" IP, which as far as I understand means not configured.

Basically the same results are returned when I run `ipconfig /all`. 3 adapters have a configured IP, while the others don't.

Now, when I tried the `GetAdaptersAddresses()`, the parsed results are following (unicast addresses only):

```json
{
  "adapters": [
    {
      "ipsV4": [
        {
          "ip": "10.x.x.x"
        }
      ],
      "ipsV6": [
        {
          "ip": "fe80::98d9:a3c0:a3a5:5b69"
        }
      ],
      "interfaceIndex": 22
    },
    {
      "ipsV4": [
        {
          "ip": "169.254.53.63"
        }
      ],
      "ipsV6": [
        {
          "ip": "fe80::7a69:f7b2:141:49af"
        }
      ],
      "interfaceIndex": 29
    },
    {
      "ipsV4": [
        {
          "ip": "169.254.89.20"
        }
      ],
      "ipsV6": [
        {
          "ip": "fe80::24a3:3460:2cb8:2934"
        }
      ],
      "interfaceIndex": 6
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

So, the adapter with index 29 (this is Bluetooth Network Connection adapter) has an IPv4 when called with `GetAdaptersAddresses()`, while it does not when calling with `GetAdaptersInfo()`. The same applies for all the other adapters aswell - any adapter that was "0.0.0.0" received some link-local IPv4 when `GetAdaptersAddresses()` was used. In addition, any adapter that did not have an IPv6 while running `ipconfig /all` received some link-local IPv6 aswell. These link-local addresses are weird however. I am not able to ping from a different machine on the same network (or from my VM) and they are not present in output of any other tool I tried (for example I tried `route print` or `arp -a`).

Can somebody please explain what is the reason for these differences and what are these IP addresses?

EDIT: I am adding the relevant code for calling `GetAdaptersAddresses()`:

```
struct AdapterInfo2 
{
    struct IpInfo {
        boost::asio::ip::address ip;
        std::string toJson() const;
    };
    std::vector<IpInfo> ipsV4;
    std::vector<IpInfo> ipsV6;
    int interfaceIndex;
    std::string name;

    std::string toJson() const;
};

std::vector<AdapterInfo2> Adapters::getSystemAdapters2()
{
    // recommended 15kB buffer
    ULONG sz = 15 * 1024;
    // we only want unicast addresses
    auto flags = GAA_FLAG_SKIP_DNS_SERVER | GAA_FLAG_SKIP_ANYCAST | GAA_FLAG_SKIP_MULTICAST;
    std::vector<BYTE> buffer(sz);

    auto res = GetAdaptersAddresses(
        AF_UNSPEC,
        flags,
        nullptr,
        (PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES)buffer.data(),
        &sz);

    // if not enough, resize and call again
    // NOTE: should be called in a loop to prevent any errors
    if (res == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) {
        buffer.resize(sz);
        res = GetAdaptersAddresses(
            AF_UNSPEC,
            flags,
            nullptr,
            (PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES)buffer.data(),
            &sz);
    }

    if (res != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        // throw
    }

    auto result = std::vector<AdapterInfo2>();

    for (auto aInfoPtr = (PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES)buffer.data(); aInfoPtr; aInfoPtr = aInfoPtr->Next) {
        AdapterInfo2 aInfo;
        aInfo.interfaceIndex = aInfoPtr->IfIndex;
        if (aInfoPtr->FriendlyName) {
            aInfo.name = narrow(aInfoPtr->FriendlyName);
        }

        for (auto pUnicast = aInfoPtr->FirstUnicastAddress; pUnicast; pUnicast = pUnicast->Next) {
            auto pUnicastAddr = pUnicast->Address.lpSockaddr;
            if (pUnicastAddr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
                auto pUnicastIpv4Addr = (sockaddr_in*)pUnicastAddr;
                auto ipv4 = boost::asio::ip::address_v4(ntohl(pUnicastIpv4Addr->sin_addr.S_un.S_addr));
                aInfo.ipsV4.push_back({ipv4});
            }
            else if (pUnicastAddr->sa_family == AF_INET6) {
                auto pUnicastIpv6Addr = (sockaddr_in6*)pUnicastAddr;
                boost::asio::ip::address_v6::bytes_type ipv6Bytes;
                std::copy(std::begin(pUnicastIpv6Addr->sin6_addr.u.Byte), std::end(pUnicastIpv6Addr->sin6_addr.u.Byte), ipv6Bytes.begin());
                auto ipv6 = boost::asio::ip::address_v6(ipv6Bytes);
                aInfo.ipsV6.push_back({ipv6});
            }
        }
        result.push_back(aInfo);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I tried various different flags. When the flags are set to 0, the result is identical.

Comment: Please show your actual code. What flags are you passing to GetAdaptersAddresses?

Comment: Code added, thanks for reaching out.

Comment: The `GetAdaptersInfo function` can retrieve information only for IPv4 addresses.

The `GetAdaptersAddresses function` can retrieve information for IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

I suggest you could try to use `GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX` instead of `Flags`. If you want to return only IPv4 addresses associated with adapters with IPv4 enabled, you could use `AF_INET` instead of `AF_UNSPEC`.

If `Flags` is zero, then unicast, anycast, and multicast IP addresses will be returned.